# Unable to get SAMLResponse from Request.Params in C# from onpremise app configured with Azure SAML SSO

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I have configured **Onpremise** MVC app with **Azure App Proxy** and **SAML SSO**.

When I browse below **onpremise** app **user access url** , I am able to redirect to onpremise app.

https://myapps.microsoft.com/signin/....

But **SAMLResponse** is missing from **Request.Params.Keys**.

I'm able to get **SAMLResponse** of request in **Fiddler** and when I decode it, I got all required logged in user related claims.

But from C#, I'm unable to get **SAMLResponse** from **Request.Params**.

I'm using below code for reading claims.

```
  foreach (string s in Request.Params.Keys)
    {
        if (s.ToString() == "SAMLResponse") // SAMLResponse is missing from Request.Params.Keys, but from Fiddler, I' able to view SAMLResponse
        {
            rawSamlData = Request.Params[s];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (rawSamlData != null)
    {
        byte[] samlData = Convert.FromBase64String(rawSamlData);

        // read back into a UTF string  
        string samlAssertion = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(samlData);

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNamespaceManager xMan = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        xMan.AddNamespace("saml2p", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");
        xMan.AddNamespace("saml2", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
        xMan.AddNamespace("ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");

        doc.LoadXml(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(samlData));
        XmlNode xNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/saml2p:Response/saml2:Assertion/saml2:AttributeStatement/saml2:Attribute[@Name='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress']", xMan);

        string NewEmailAddressCliams = null;
        foreach (XmlNode x in xNode)
        {
            NewEmailAddressCliams += x.InnerText; // Email address returned from claim.
        }              
    }
```

If I get **SAMLResponse** in **Fiddler**, then I am supposed to get **SAMLResponse** from C# aswell using **Request.Params** but it is not happening.

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Hi @Chandra, Request.Params is a combination of the keys/values pairs(collection) which already contains your SAML information .you need to loop through it to get the exact data.

Answer (score 0):

Moving answer from comments,

*`Request.Params`* is a combination of the keys/values pairs(collection) which already contains your SAML information .you need to loop through it to get the exact data.